# How to ignore Control+C (copy) on web browser

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I'm trying to ignore <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> in my website but im stuck.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script language="javascript">
            function whichButton(event)
            {
                if (event.button==2)//RIGHT CLICK
                {
                    alert("Not Allow Right Click!");
                }

            }
            function noCTRL(e)
            {
                var code = (document.all) ? event.keyCode:e.which;

                var msg = "Sorry, this functionality is disabled.";
                if (parseInt(code)==17) //CTRL
                {
                    alert(msg);
                    window.event.returnValue = false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="">
            <strong>Not Allow Paste </strong><BR>
            <input type="text" value="" onMouseDown="whichButton(event)" onKeyDown="return noCTRL(event)"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried this code, but it is can only ignore right click.

How can I ignore <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>?

Comment: [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your body tag adds these events

```
<body oncontextmenu="return noMenu();" onkeydown="return noKeys(event);">
```

and you then define these functions in your `<head>` section, you can take action when the context menu is activated (right click) or when keys are pressed on your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function noMenu()
{
    alert("Not Allow Right Click!");
    return false;
}

function noKeys(event)
{
    if (event == null) event = window.event;
    // here you can check event.keyCode
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have a problem..

I just need ctrl + c and ctrl + a but this code blocking all key events. 

Example; [I cant write this]

Comment: the commment `here you can check event.keyCode` indicates the point at which you'll want to customize this code for that keys you wish to reject.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [at this website](http://www.hypergurl.com/norightclick)

But if someone wants to copy your content, they can. It will just make it harder and more time consuming to use.

### And also

Regarding this Ctrl-C you could add javascript to block it, but it is useless, since the user can always disable javascript. In fact many users will find interception of right-click very annoying.

All these could have a meaning if you are building an intranet application or you can ship an integrated browser for users to view the application. With public html, I believe it isn't even worth trying. One solution would be to build your application with flash or another plug-in. This way you can encrypt everything you've sent to the client.