# How to disable selection of text on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make webpage very native.
How to remove select,select all property in webpage?

Comment: You got so far three extremely different answers: maybe you should specify better what "native" exactly means to you and what you want  to remove

Comment: What you are trying to do is prevent the user from selecting text with dragging the mouse and copy it or using CTRL+A (Windows) to select everything and copy it, right?

Comment: ya, correct. prevent the user from selecting the whole webpage, not only text, everything in webpage

Comment: @Pavlo This not a duplicate of that. That is about removing the highlight, this about removing the possibility to copy anything from the webpage. So it is a duplicate, but of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958478/how-to-disable-copy-paste-browser

Comment: @selva And on that question, check the following answer by [Christoph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1047823/christoph), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958478/how-to-disable-copy-paste-browser#comment12718729_9958478

Comment: @HenrikAmmer we are designing offline site. we need to give some restrictions.So we need to prevent the user from selecting properties.anyway thanx dude.

Comment: @selva What do you mean by „property“?

Comment: @pavlo property is a function. for example visibility property,display property, selecting etc.. am i right?

Comment: @selva Yes, `visibility`, `display`, `user-select` are CSS properties. But you can't „select“ them, you can only set them with what's called CSS declaration. Check my answer.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

### Disable selection of every element with CSS

```
body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
```

This is supported by Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE 10, and iOS Devices. More info on [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select).

**Edit:** If you want `<input>` and `<textarea>` to remain selectable in Firefox, add:

```
input,
textarea {
     -moz-user-select: text;
}
```

### Disable context menu with jQuery

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: Saves my day. I did not know this can be so simple in CSS. I tried whole day using javascript and found this.

Answer (score 8):

use this code https://www.docsity.com/it/teorie-e-pratiche-del-web-4/556038/

```
body, html{     
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;  
}
```

Comment: Nice. I used this, but without the `body` tag. Is there any reason for having the `body` tag when it's already being applied to the entire html?

Answer (score 2):

This JavaScript will Disable select, copy and paste of the content
But if user will save page to local machine they will be able to do "anything" they want with your code.

```
//disable cut copy past
var message = "";
function clickIE() { if (document.all) { (message); return false; } }
function clickNS(e) {
    if(document.layers || (document.getElementById && !document.all)) {
        if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) { (message); return false; }
    }
}
if (document.layers)
{ document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); document.onmousedown = clickNS; }
else { document.onmouseup = clickNS; document.oncontextmenu = clickIE; }
 document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false")


//for disable select option
document.onselectstart = new Function('return false');
function dMDown(e) { return false; }
function dOClick() { return true; }
document.onmousedown = dMDown;
document.onclick = dOClick;
```

Comment: Works in wpf web browser!

Answer (score 1):

You Can disable by adding attribute in your body tag oncontextmenu="return false;

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

Comment: [Obstructive JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) is considered to be a bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

may this help you

```
<div onselectstart="return false;" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
```

Comment: A good start but doesn't prevent select all (CTRL+A in Windows) in my test though.

Answer (score -1):

```
element_name{
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none; 
   user-select: none;
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.