# Click on a <label> twice select the text instead of toggling the einput

Tags: html, css, input, label

I've got an input element inside a label element (don't want to use id):

```
<label class="inline-block-class">
    <input type="radio/checkbox" class="hidden-class" />
    <span><img src="mimic-input-element.png" /> some text</span>
</label>
```

It all works well, but when I'm clicking the label twice in a row, trying toggling the input on and off, it works only for the first click. The second one is just 'selecting' the elements on screen.

How can I prevent this behaviour? I want to give the label a native feel, like clicking on the real thing.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/soLuwwy3/

Comment: you could use -webkit-user-select:none; and browser equivalents on your span but then you won't be able to select the text

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315476/how-to-disable-selection-of-text-on-a-web-page). Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soLuwwy3/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

few lines of css will do this for you:

```
label span {
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}
```

your jsfiddle edited:
http://jsfiddle.net/soLuwwy3/5/

Answer (score 2):

To make your span text not selectable  use `user-select: none`.

more info [**user-select**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

```
label span {
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jkjbqxna/)

Comment: @Harry:no need of it,just none is enough,its a typo error