# How to disable copy option of web browsers for android and ios phones

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am working on php assignment, where data is getting displayed in a tabular form. As per requirement user can only select data from a particular column only. All this is working well on laptop but when it is tested on a mobile phone, SELECT ALL and COPY options allow data of entire page getting copied. I have also tried pointer-events:none, but it is not working as required. Please help....

Comment: you can refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315476/how-to-disable-selection-of-text-on-a-web-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable selection of text on a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315476/how-to-disable-selection-of-text-on-a-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS for this.

```
$('#column-with-disabled-copy').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but it is not working for me. Is there any way to disable copy option in mobile phone browser. I have already block right click, ctrl +C and other copy options for the particular web page and is working well for any desktop, but my main area of concern is small screen devices.