# Disable Copy-Paste from the Text Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, copy-paste

```html
@if (Model.CanMaintainNcrLineManagement) {
<tr>
  <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { id = "txArNcrLineDescriptionValue", @style = "height:520px" })</td>
</tr>
} else {
<tr class="read-only-editor">
  <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { id = "txArNcrLineDescriptionReadOnly", @style = "height:520px" })</td>
</tr>
}
```

I want to disable the copy-past option from the text editor box. I have used below both codes to disable it but its not working. Please give me some solution

```js
$('body').bind('copy paste', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<body oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Disable Copy Paste (Browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958478/how-to-disable-copy-paste-browser)

Comment: Which text editor?

Comment: I am using kendo Text Editor

Comment: Does editory have an Id ? I think it does't work on body.

Comment: Yes Id is there

Comment: @MeghanaKM can you edit your question and put some more html.

Comment: @MeghanaKM it is for "body" or "textarea"?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { $('#txArNcrLineDescriptionValue').bind('copy paste', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }); });    I have edited Like this

Answer (score 0):

Change your code and your text editor must be inside body tag and will prevent all inside body tag.

```
<body oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">
```

To

```
<body onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false">
```

Comment: I Added Above line in <body> , no changes

Comment: I am Testing in IE

Comment: Ok let me check in IE

Comment: No its not disabling Copy and Paste

Comment: Its working for me in both chrome and IE. What is id of your text editor ?

Comment: id = "txArNcrLineDescriptionValue" which is used in html

Comment: can you please try this $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#txArNcrLineDescriptionValue').on("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});

Comment: Thank you replying,, I tried this before I posting this question that also not worked,, its worked for whole page,, but i am trying to do for only Text Editor

Comment: Try removing oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false" events from body tag

Comment: Ya I Have done that  and like this $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txArNcrLineDescriptionValue').bind('copy paste', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in Chrome 66.0.3359.181, I.E. 11, and FireFox 59.0.3 and it is disabling copying and pasting into anything in the body or the input.

```js
 $('body').bind('copy paste', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); return false;
    });
```

```html
<body oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">
```

Comment: Yes Thanks for reply,, Ya its working for me now i used text ID and used this code inside Script Body where i called

Comment: If this helped answer your question please accept it as answered instead of commenting.