# completely Disable copy past in input box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I try lot of javascript and php for completely remove copy past to my site ..
but lot of Plugins available for override copy past.. example plugin for chrome "[Don't F*** With Paste](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-fuck-with-paste/nkgllhigpcljnhoakjkgaieabnkmgdkb?hl=en)"

Any one know how to save my site? i need disable my copy past completely in my inputbox

```
Email: <input type="textbox" id="email"><br/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        const myInput = document.getElementById('email');
        myInput.onpaste = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
```

this also not work

```
onCopy="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" 
onPaste="return false"
```

this one also not work with that plugins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Disable Copy Paste (Browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958478/how-to-disable-copy-paste-browser)

Comment: You are being downvoted due to vulgar language which is not allowed on SE sites. You will find more people willing to help you if the question is worded without such. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233

Comment: @Geek Stocks: [That really isn't his fault.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-fuck-with-paste/nkgllhigpcljnhoakjkgaieabnkmgdkb?hl=en) Though, admittedly, he could've chosen to link to the extension without naming it outright...

Comment: @BoltClock: I try to help OP's understand why they get a downvote instead of just moving on. I find commenting on the situation helps. Agree with you that I hope he edits...soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<input type="text" oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="if ((arguments[0] || window.event).ctrlKey) return false">
```

Comment: yes its work thank.. just i tested with different plugins

Comment: @RajMohammed No problem whatsoever!